# Using endswith with case insensitivity in python

Tags: python, regex, string, os.walk

I have a list of file extensions and I have to write if conditions. Something like

```py
ext = (".dae", ".xml", ".blend", ".bvh", ".3ds", ".ase",
           ".obj", ".ply", ".dxf", ".ifc", ".nff", ".smd",
           ".vta", ".mdl", ".md2", ".md3",
           ".pk3", ".mdc", ".x",
           ".q3o", ".q3s", ".raw",
           ".ac", ".dxf", ".irrmesh",
           ".irr", ".off", ".ter",
           ".mdl", ".hmp", ".mesh.xml",
           ".skeleton.xml", ".material", ".ms3dv",
           ".lwo", ".lws", ".lxo",
           ".csm", ".cob", ".scn",
           ".xgl", ".zgl")
for folder, subfolders, filename in os.walk(directory):
    if any([filename.endswith(tuple(ext)) for filename in filenames]):
```

I realized that `endswith` is case sensitive. How I could treat, for instance, ".xml" and ".XML" as the same extensions?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply call [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to make the string lowercase before calling `endswith`:

```
ext = (".dae", ".xml", ".blend", ".bvh", ".3ds", ".ase",
           ".obj", ".ply", ".dxf", ".ifc", ".nff", ".smd",
           ".vta", ".mdl", ".md2", ".md3"
           ".pk3", ".mdc", ".x"
           ".q3o", ".q3s", ".raw"
           ".ac", ".dxf", ".irrmesh"
           ".irr", ".off", ".ter"
           ".mdl", ".hmp", ".mesh.xml"
           ".skeleton.xml", ".material", ".ms3dv"
           ".lwo", ".lws", ".lxo"
           ".csm", ".cob", ".scn"
           ".xgl", ".zgl")
for folder, subfolders, filename in os.walk(directory):
    if any([filename.lower().endswith(tuple(ext)) for filename in filenames]):
```

Comment: Don't forget to first ensure the variable is not `None` otherwise `lower()` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old answer but since Python 3.3, there exists the `casefold()` method which is more aggressive than `lower()` and is the more natural caseless string matching. So something like the following is an option:

```py
filename.casefold().endswith(ext)
```

On a tangential note, `any()` short-circuits, meaning it stops at the first True, so it is much faster if `any()` is called on a generator expression instead of a list (especially if the matching string is towards the beginning of a long list) because with genexpr, we can stop the `endswith` check right away while with list, we have to perform the `endswith` check for every string before the `any()` evaluation.

So instead of

```py
any([filename.lower().endswith(ext) for filename in filenames])
#   ^                                                        ^  <--- list
```

use

```py
any(filename.lower().endswith(ext) for filename in filenames)
#  ^                                                        ^   <--- genexpr
```

---

Finally, since this question is tagged regex, here's a regex solution as well. Simply compile a pattern that ignores case and search whether the pattern matches.

```py
import re
pat = re.compile(fr"({'|'.join(re.escape(e) for e in ext)})$", re.I)
for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    if any(pat.search(filename) for filename in filenames):
        # do something
```

Comment: It is important to remember that case insensitivity using `str,casefold()` is different to case insensitivity in regular expressions using `re.I`. One uses full case folding, the other simple casefolding. Results for some languages differ between the two behaviours. One of the gotchas in Python.